# Java JDK minor updates regarding Security Issues

Tags: java, eclipse, security

Lets say I have a `Java 8` Web-Application, which is build and released on my local computer. On this computer I have the JDK Version `JDK 8u11` installed, which I use to compile the application for a release.

On the PROD-Environment, I am using `JDK 8u60`.

Now, lets assume a critical security vulnerability of JDK 8, which was in `JDK 8u11` and `JDK 8u60`, gets fixed by Oracle. Therefore Oracle releases Java `JDK 8u65`.

**What do I need to do in order to have a secure application:**

1. Update the JDK Version of my computer, to compile the application with the `JDK 8u65` and to deploy it on PROD to get rid of the security vulnerability

OR

2. Do I just need to update the JDK of my PROD-Environment, to have the security issue closed?

If you need any further information, please ask.

Comment: On the server side, since this is where the runtime libraries are .

Comment: did you ever notice that when you need a security update to java on your computer its only the jre that gets updated and not the applications? so yup the runtime contains the security. if i am not mistaken the only reason to recompile a program for a jdk/jre update is if the jdk brings about new functions such as lamda in java 8.

Comment: Security updates rarely prompt a recompilation of applications. However it is not unheard of, particularly if you were using deprecated or unsupported features and configurations that you need to change your build to work with newer versions.

Comment: Could it be, that the compiler introduced a security issue in JDK 8, which is then fixed in the JDK 8u65 (to stick to my example). Therefore, I would need a recompilation of the Application or can't this be the case?

Comment: Note that if you are using Eclipse it doesn't use the JDK javac compiler for builds.